# popen command not giving required output

Tags: python

I am using the below code to run a git command "git tag -l contains ad0beef66e5890cde6f0961ed03d8bc7e3defc63" ..if I run this command standalone I see the required output..but through the below program,it doesnt work,does anyone have any inputs on what could be wrong?

```
from subprocess import check_call,Popen,PIPE
revtext = "ad0beef66e5890cde6f0961ed03d8bc7e3defc63"
proc = Popen(['git', 'tag', '-l', '--contains', revtext ],stdout=PIPE ,stderr=PIPE)
(out, error) = proc.communicate()
print "OUT"
print out
```

Comment: What does `error` contain?

Comment: Perhaps the python script has changed directories before it makes this call.  Check the working directory of `proc`.